# How to get local axis orientation in Python?

Tags: python, scripting

How to get orientation of the local axis in python?

[image]

Comment: Isn't it the object orientation? `Object.matrix_world`

Answer (score 3):

As Codemax answered. Thanks to him. Here is an example how i can rotate Localy an active object at Y-Axis.

```
activeObj = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
activeObjMatrix = activeObj.matrix_world
theAxis = (activeObjMatrix[0][1], activeObjMatrix[1][1], activeObjMatrix[2][1])
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=rotateValue, axis=theAxis)
```

Comment: You don't give any details on rotateValue. I take it that's an XYZ vector, like (1.5,3,.71) and in radians?

Comment: @Tango it's a float value, in radians. With a value of pi/2 you will rotate 90° around local Y axis. By the way for X local axis and Z local axis just replace the second index in each element of `theAxis` by 0 or 2 respectively

Comment: @Gorgious: Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple theorem of linear algebra to do this:

'Every column of the (3 by 3)transformation matrix is the (unit) vector along rotated(transformed) axis'

You can use the following code to achieve the goal of this theorem:

```
Import bpy
From mathutils import Vector

obj = bpy.context.active_object
mat = obj.matrix_world
localX = Vector((mat[0][0],mat[1][0],mat[2][0]))
localY = Vector((mat[0][1],mat[1][1],mat[2][1]))
localZ = Vector((mat[0][2],mat[1][2],mat[2][2]))
```